# Unable to find user by stripe customer ID on new subscription event (Cashier)

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

My aim is to send an email to the user when a Laravel cashier subscription is created (I use stripe checkout) but my cashier event listener isn't able to find a user with the given stripe customer ID.

My guess is that I'm looking for the customer ID too soon in the subscription flow before it can be added by Cashier, I can see the webhook terminal output and it processes the subscription but when I debug my listener, the user query is null. (It can't find a user with that customer id)

```
class StripeEventListener
{
    public function handle(WebhookReceived $event): void
    {
        // New subscription
        if ($event->payload['type'] === 'customer.subscription.created') {

            $customerId = $event->payload['data']['object']['customer'];

            $user = User::where('stripe_id', $customerId)->first();

            Log::debug('data from listener', ['user_result' => $user, 'customer_id' => $customerId]);

            if ($user) {
                Mail::to($user)->queue(new NewSubscriptionMail($user));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The log has the following (from a feature test)

> [2023-11-08 13:53:37] local.DEBUG: data from listener
> {"user_result":null,"customer_id":"cus_Oy8Tp1jrJ8ORq9"}

As I use Stripe Checkout, my controller redirects to Stripe and it doesn't handle any subscription creation itself, my only option is to listen for the event.

If anybody has any ideas, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you registering/creating the customer first in stripe? you can do that with `$stripeCustomer = $user->createAsStripeCustomer();` i'll assume that you already made your User model `Billable`, the migrations, etc... You can retrieve the user doing this too `$user = Cashier::findBillable($customerId);`

Comment: In order to do what you want to do, you first need to register the customer in stripe when the user registers on your app, or perform a check when the user logs in to check if it's already a stripe customer, if not, create a new stripe customer. If your customers aren't registered first, every time you perform a sub request or a payment request to stripe, it will create a new customer.

Comment: @ZeNix Laravel Cashier is configured in my app and has tests, I'm looking to add email notices for when certain events happen now. I just checked and Cashier is creating the stripe customer itself.

I added the createAsStripeCustomer method to my UserObserver and I think I've found the problem. Stripe is searching for a completely different customer ID.

[2023-11-08 15:14:11] local.DEBUG: Processing a new subscription event. {"user_result":null,"customer_id":"cus_Oy9lfJaPWKMe7I","user":"cus_Ox5bIlzfhMvgyi","user_count":1}

Comment: I know stripe create's the customer itself, but if you don't previous register it, stripe will be creating a new client every time you make a transaction, I've had that problem before, so whenever you receive a webhook event from stripe it will contain a complete different stripe customer id than the one you've stored in your database.

Comment: I will post an answer of how I made it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In stripe you'll need to first register the client in order to proceed with transactions, so for example in my LoginController I've something like this:

After the login is processed:

```
    $user = Auth::user();
    $stripeCustomer = Cashier::findBillable($user->stripe_id);
    $authUser = User::find($user->id);
    if(!$stripeCustomer){
        $authUser->createAsStripeCustomer();
    }
```

You can even update the balance from stripe to the user right after:

```
    $authUser->update([
        'balance' => (float)preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $authUser->balance()),
    ]);
```

In your User model you make sure to have the data synced between stripe and your app:

```
protected static function booted(): void
{
    static::updated(queueable(function (User $customer) {
        if ($customer->hasStripeId()) {
            $customer->syncStripeCustomerDetails();
        }
    }));
}
```

Then you can perform a transaction in your controller or whenever you're doing it:

```
    $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
    $user->newSubscription('default', 'your_price_id_goes_here')->add();
```

Now you can expect for webhook events, since you're waiting for the `customer.subscription.created` I strongly recommend that you use the `customer.subscription.updated` event, since the `created` it's created before the subscription is even confirmed, so you'll be sending emails even when is just a intent of a subscription or transaction.

You can do it like this to handle more than one type of `$event`

```
public function handle(WebhookReceived $event): void
{
    if($event->payload)
    {
        switch($event->payload['type'])
        {
            case 'customer.subscription.updated';
                // Yor code goes here
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [Cashier docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/billing), you’ll see there’s a section specifically on using Checkout to create subscriptions: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/billing#subscription-checkouts

You should be redirecting from your controller by chaining a `checkout` call to a `newSubscription` call:

```
Route::get('/subscription-checkout', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user()
        ->newSubscription('default', 'price_monthly')
        ->checkout();
});
```

If you do, then Cashier creates the customer in Stripe for you (if needed) before redirected to checkout: https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/503d6a0ee03b4a070ee0de086eb248738debd3d7/src/Checkout.php#L80

You then also don’t need to explicitly handle checkout-related webhooks because again, Cashier’s built-in webhook controller will create the subscription records in your database based on the webhook events Stripe sends.

So if you are using Cashier, then you shouldn’t be trying to manually create checkout sessions, or manually handle subscription webhooks.